# Preloader not working when the website loaded in iPhone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, preloader

Can someone help me why my preloader won't work if the website is opened using iPhone?

It is working on android phone and laptop. The loader should be animated, but it only static on iPhone.
I'm using AJAX to POST the data when user click login and show the loader. Here is my code. Below is the image from iPhone. Please help.

CSS :

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates:400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Eczar);

.dx-context_bg {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.pre_loader-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pre_loader {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 49%;
  width: 58px;
  height: 86px;
  margin-top: -43px;
  margin-left: -29px;
  font-family: "Bookman Old Style", sans-serif;
  line-height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: Loader 10s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: Loader 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.pre_loader * {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Loader {
  5%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    width: 58px;
    margin-left: -29px;/* Prevent Object Moment from Beginning */
  }
  40%,
  82% {
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: -65px;
  }
  86%,
  100% {
    width: 4px;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
}

@keyframes Loader {
  5%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    width: 58px;
    margin-left: -29px;/* Prevent Object Moment from Beginning */
  }
  40%,
  82% {
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: -65px;
  }
  86%,
  100% {
    width: 4px;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
}
.pre_loader .dx_rectangle {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 58px;
  height: 66px;
  border: 2px solid #313131;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.pre_loader .dx_rectangle span {
  left: 24px;
  bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
  animation: FillSpan 10s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: FillSpan 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.pre_loader .dx_rectangle.dx_outlines {
  animation: Outlines 10s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: Outlines 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.pre_loader .dx_rectangle.dx_fill {
  height: 4px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  animation: Fill 10s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: Fill 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.pre_loader .dx_rectangle.dx_fill span {
  color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Outlines {
  82% {
    width: 58px;
    height: 66px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    width: 4px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  85%,
  86% {
    height: 86px;
    border-width: 2px;
  }
  89%,
  100% {
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes Outlines {
  82% {
    width: 58px;
    height: 66px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    width: 4px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  85%,
  86% {
    height: 86px;
    border-width: 2px;
  }
  89%,
  100% {
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes Fill {
  30%,
  100% {
    height: 66px;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: #3e3e3e;
  }
  40%,
  100% {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
  82% {
    width: 58px;
    height: 66px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    width: 4px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  85%,
  86% {
    height: 86px;
    border-width: 2px;
  }
  89%,
  100% {
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes Fill {
  30%,
  100% {
    height: 66px;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: #3e3e3e;
  }
  40%,
  100% {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
  82% {
    width: 58px;
    height: 66px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    width: 4px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  85%,
  86% {
    height: 86px;
    border-width: 2px;
  }
  89%,
  100% {
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes FillSpan {
  80% {
    left: 24px;
  }
  84%,
  100% {
    left: -34px;
  }
  82% {
    bottom: 3px;
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    bottom: 9px;
  }
}

@keyframes FillSpan {
  80% {
    left: 24px;
  }
  84%,
  100% {
    left: -34px;
  }
  82% {
    bottom: 3px;
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    bottom: 9px;
  }
}
.pre_loader .dx_rinkin_coffee {
  left: -220px;
  top: 19px;
  width: fit-content;
  animation: rinkinCoffee 10s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rinkinCoffee 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.pre_loader .dx_rinkin_coffee span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  color: #313131;
}
.pre_loader .dx_rinkin_coffee span.dx_rinkin {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.pre_loader .dx_rinkin_coffee span.dx_coffee {
  font-family: "Monospace", serif;
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rinkinCoffee {
  30% {
    left: -220px;
  }
  40%,
  82% {
    left: 62px;
  }
  86%,
  100% {
    left: -260px;
  }
}

@keyframes rinkinCoffee {
  30% {
    left: -220px;
  }
  40%,
  82% {
    left: 62px;
  }
  86%,
  100% {
    left: -260px;
  }
}
.pre_loader .dx_slogan {
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #313131;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: Slogan 10s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: Slogan 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Slogan {
  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  48%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  81% {
    right: 2px;
  }
  86%,
  100% {
    right: 58px;
  }
}

@keyframes Slogan {
  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  48%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  81% {
    right: 2px;
  }
  86%,
  100% {
    right: 58px;
  }
}
```

jQuery :

```
$("#login-btn").click(function(){
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  console.log("login button click");
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: baseURL + "login/user_login_new",
       dataType : 'json',
       data: {
            username:username,
            password:password},
       beforeSend: function(){
        $("#newloader").show();
       },
       success: function(response){
                // console.log(response);
                 if(response == 1){
                    console.log("success");
                    window.location.href = baseURL + "dashboard/view";
                 }else if(response == 0){
                    console.log("failed");
                    window.location.href = "login";
                 }else if(response == 2){
                    var previousURL = "<?php  echo $this->session->userdata('previous_url'); ?>";
                    console.log("success");
                    window.location.href = previousURL;
                 }
       },
       complete : function() {
            console.log("complete");
        // This will run after sending an Ajax complete
        }
      });

});
```

[image: Here is the image when the website is opened using iPhone]

Comment: give link to check

Comment: @Tausif even if you had a link you need to login to the website to see the preloader.

Comment: @miorfarhan at least provide us with the css or js of the preloader. The code above only toggles it's visibility but contains nothing of the actual animation.

Comment: @user6 I've updated my css code, I only use css.